# Android, get app size

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to calculate the size of an installed Android application/package. I can't find this information in neither ApplicationInfo nor PackageInfo objects. From the ApplicationInfo I can get the path for the data and the app itself. Data is a directory structure, but when attempting to read it recursivly I get a nullpointer. Is there any better way of doing it? Any sample code?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size

Answer (score 5):

If you look at [ManageApplications.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/settings/ManageApplications.java), you'll see that they use the hidden getPackageSizeInfo method of the PackageManager. This isn't part of the public API, so you shouldn't really use it.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size) an example of how you shouldn't use it!