# Android, Get Installed App Size and Date

Tags: android

In Android, How I can get app installed date and how I can get installed app size.

I am using below code to get app size but it is not correct

List packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

```
for(i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
    ApplicationInfo appInfo =p.applicationInfo;
    long fileSize = new FileInputStream(appInfo.sourceDir).getChannel().size();
}
```

Please help me.. 
Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android, get app size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065149/android-get-app-size)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ajay,

To get the installation date you will want to use the [`PackageManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class.  More specifically the [`getPackageInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method.  This will return to you a [`PackageInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) object which contains [`firstInstallTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#firstInstallTime) value.

There does not currently exist a public API to get an application's size as `PackageManager.getpackageSizeInfo()` was removed from the API from SDK 0.9 to SDK 1.0. See [HERE](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/df94daae34336aad/f96a8425549c6637)

Good luck!

Comment: Do we have any way to calculate the size/disk usage of installed application.

Answer (score 2):

For the size of a package you may try the standard "Java way", thus:

```
ApplicationInfo appInfo = ...;

try{
    File file = new File(appInfo.sourceDir);
    double size = file.length();  // size in Byte
    Log.d(TAG, "Size: " + size + " Byte\n");
} catch( Exception e ) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Not sure it gives you a precise estimation of the size, though.

Comment: This will return only the APK file size. there are many other folders to consider, some of them are protected.