# get information of install app in android

Tags: android

> hello expert, i need build app that share mobile app to second mobile so that
>   i need know that how can i get all app information like : name,date,icon,etc.
>   package com.AppInfo;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AppInfo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     private ListView lView;
     private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        }}
class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    private void prettyPrint() {
       // Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);

    }


private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout this : http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon

Comment: i refer this link but i got a problem.

Comment: List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

Comment: can you tell me how can i get icon and date of app

Comment: can you tell me how can i get date by gerPackageManager() ?

Comment: For all the info that we can get , please see this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html .

Comment: plz refer my entire question and after you suggest me

Comment: Are you getting all the other info of the Installed  Application using the above link.

Comment: plz checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311644/get-application-installed-date-on-android

Comment: i know this thing but 
firstInstallTime method are not supported, it raise error

Comment: This method is supported for **API Level 9 upwards**. For lower levels i dont think there is anything to find the date of the installed app.

Comment: ya you are right API Level 9 are supported.
but when i am print it to logcat , it display like " firstInstallTime is :::::::1295484763000"
so can you tell me about this?

Answer (score 1):

Although the info you want can be retrieved using [getInstalledPackages()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29) and using [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html)

But as you want to share the app from one phone to another I dont think its possible atleast unless the device is rooted

Comment: yeh ! i refer it but is there any example of it

Comment: i refer this link but i got a problem

Comment: List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);

Comment: Are you using the above code from context of an Activity and post your code here

Comment: In your code After setContentView() close only one brace and on the last line add one brace

Comment: ya i got it run perfectly now lets check it to me

Comment: hai dud it is only get app information of current app right? i need to  information of app that are install in device or previously created in emulator so can you give me hint?

Comment: No, its give info of all app installed Arrylist res contain all the info that you want

Comment: so any suggestion to do that?

Comment: can you tell me how can i get date and icon of app?

Comment: For icon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384713/how-to-get-the-icon-of-other-applications-android and for date http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315586/android-get-installed-app-size-and-date

Comment: PackageManager paa = null;
        try {
   paa.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), i);
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
i have try this but i cant understand that from where i get date only

Comment: the link I have posted its mentioned there in paa object you will get firstInstallTime and thats what you need you have to convert time into Date many examples are there on net follow them

Comment: I have try following code in my application

PackageInfo manager=getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
But manager  object  cant contain any firstInstallTime method , so can you help me this topic.

Answer (score 0):

C2MD is nice to send small amount of data  and its fairly easy to implement. If you dont want to do that just send a sms to the other phone and have a receiver on the second mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the information you need using the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html), both [ApplicationInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) and [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) may be used.

```
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";  
...

final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final List<ApplicationInfo> installedApps = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for ( ApplicationInfo app : installedApps ) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Package: " + app.packageName);
    Log.d(TAG, "Directory: " + app.sourceDir);
    Log.d(TAG, "Icon: " + app.icon);

    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(app.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        Date installTime = new Date( packageInfo.firstInstallTime );
        Date updateTime = new Date( packageInfo.lastUpdateTime );

        Log.d(TAG, "Installed: " + installTime.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Updated: " + updateTime.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Version: " + packageInfo.versionCode);
        Log.d(TAG, "Name: " + packageInfo.versionName);
    }
    catch ( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```