# how to check how much space is taken by an application

Tags: android

Is it possible to get the amount of memory taken by an (any) application on an Android device (internal storage & SD card) via the Android SDK (programmatically)?
If it's possible - how it can be done?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065149/android-get-app-size http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size

Answer (score -1):

open the **DDMS** perspective (just know it for Eclipse for sure), then choose the

> System information
>   -Tab

and there you can see the **CPU-Load** or the **Memory-Usage** in realtime.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. It is possible.
In the Emulator,
Go to Settings-->Apps. Then you will see the list of apps with the memory size. 
You can also see the free space of internal storage.

Comment: I know that way - that's why I wrote "via the Android SDK" but since it was not very clear I added "programmatically". thanks anyway.

Comment: I thought, it is not possible via Android SDK