# How to get app size in android

Tags: android

I had search lot but i am not finding any best solution for getting app size.we can get app size through aidl (IPackageStatsObserver.class,PackageStats).but i am not doing this.Is it legal way to get app size through aidl.

Anyone help me.

Comment: Not saying it is or not, just trying to understand the question; why would it not be "legal" to do so?

Comment: This link says http://stackoverflow.com/a/2605838/576573

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [ManageApplications.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.2_r1.1/com/android/settings/ManageApplications.java), you'll see that they use the hidden getPackageSizeInfo method of the PackageManager. This isn't part of the public API, so you shouldn't really use it.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size) an example of how you shouldn't use it!

Comment: I have problem in importing IPackageStatsObserver.class.How can do?