# Android::What does PackageStats.codeSize indicate?

Tags: android, package, android-package-managers, appstats, code-size

I am korean software developer and can speak english not very well.

I ask for your understanding.

Anyway...

I've got the code size(long) from packagestats.

Related Links:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageStats.html

[Getting installed app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size)

However,

I don't know what codeSize represent.

Someone says codeSize is the size of APK.

I can't make sure of that.

Because there are not only APK files but resource files like odex files, image files,

sound files, ttf files and so on.

At the beginning, I did want to know each full package size

so I did get sum of codeSize, dataSize, cacheSize and external things.

I am not sure of that is full package size.

Plz, advice for me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your APK file contains the program's code (.dex files), resources, assets, certificates, and manifest file. So the codeSize gives the size of APK, basically a zip file which includes everything.

Comment: // Thank you for your answer. That's right.
I have had another question. 
Does it include the size of shared library like *.so file?? 
Is there any shared resources?

Comment: Yes, the compressed versions of your shared libraries (*.so) get packaged inside your apk.

Comment: I've thought that application not exist as APK(likes ZIP) file but just exist as executable file with resources on virtual machine.