# Get Size Of A Package

Tags: java, android, size

I am trying to do a simple application manager app and I couldn't manage to get the specific package size and that's the only thing left for me to do.

I tried calculating using `BlockSize(StatFs)` but that didn't work.  I want to get the size in MB.

Comment: Could you add more code / context?  As is, what you're trying to do and what you've tried is still unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting installed app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size)

Answer (score 0):

this may help you... this will give the size in bytes...

```
public static long getPackageSize(Context context,String packageName) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName,PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES);
        File file = new File(applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
        return file.length();
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so to convert this to megabytes i need to divide this with 1024?for example : long file.length()/1024

Comment: long kb = bytes/1024;
long mb = kb/1024;

Comment: I keep getting 0,and ive tired it for serval packages

Comment: do i need any premissions for this function?