# How to get the size of installed application?

Tags: android, size, apk, filesize

I am trying to calculate the size of the installed application.

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size)

I have tested it on some devices, and there is no problem except Samsung Galaxy Note3(4.3).

I get this error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getPackageSizeInfo()

I'm wondering is there any other way to get the size of an installed app?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this...

```
public static long getApkSize(Context context, String packageName)
        throws NameNotFoundException {
    return new File(context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
            packageName, 0).publicSourceDir).length();
}
```

Comment: I think have to use this method as a backup alternative.

Comment: This is the "APK" file size, not the installed app size

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link will help you:

http://nsamteladze.blogspot.com/2012/10/get-apks-code-size-in-android.html

Basically he is making use of the concept of *reflection*, which is a powerful tool but not always advisable. Read more about it here :[What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) and if it is suitable for you, make use of it.

Comment: I have already followed the way that blog said,and I think I have to use the size of the apk file as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get Size of apps without AIDL Files** -------> Kotlin Language

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)  
        
    val list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,0)
            
    // Set adapter to LIST VIEW
    listView.adapter = getApps(list)
 }
       
 private fun getApps(List: MutableList<ResolveInfo>): List<AppData> {
            
     val list = ArrayList<AppData>()
      for (packageInfo in List) {
                      
         val packageName = packageInfo.activityInfo.packageName
           // return size in form of Bytes(Long)             
    val size = File(packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName,0).publicSourceDir).length()
          
          val item = AppData(Size)
            list += item
      }
   return list
   }
}
 // Make Data Class
data class AppData(val size: Long)
```

*Remember to convert it in MB from Bytes*