# Display Application Size In Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to display the size of every application installed in my phone! How can I achieve this? I tried this:

```
PackageStats ps = new PackageStats(packageInfo.packageName);
int size = ps.codeSize;
```

I am getting a 0 value every time. Please help me

Comment: Eclipse is just a tool you are using and is used to develop all sorts of things in many languages. What programming language? What type of phone?

Comment: programming language android mobile moto e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Getting installed app size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size)

> Unfortunately there is currently no official way to do that. However,
>   you can call the PackageManager's hidden getPackageSize method if you
>   import the PackageStats and IPackageStatsObserver AIDLs into our
>   project and generate the stubs. You can then use reflection to invoke
>   getPackageSize:
>
> ```
> PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
>
> Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
>     "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);
>
> getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, "com.android.mms",
>     new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
>             throws RemoteException {
>
>             Log.i(TAG, "codeSize: " + pStats.codeSize);
>         }
>     });
> ```
>
> That's obviously a big hack and should not be used for public
>   applications.
>
> Android Package Size Using AIDL with Eclipse and ADT APK Piracy: Using
>   private code & resources in Android

You would then need to iterate through each application and put the package name within the invoke(...) method.