# Size of other apps in Android O

Tags: android

I used to get the package size of all installed app with

```
Method getPackageSizeInfo = null;
        try {
            getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
                    "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class,
                    IPackageStatsObserver.class);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            LogIt.e(this, e.toString());
        }
```

Nevertheless this is not possible in Android O anymore and Android feels offended:

```
D/ApplicationPackageManager: Shame on you for calling the hidden API getPackageSizeInfoAsUser(). Shame!
```

Is there a workaround to get the size of the other apps?

Comment: Have you define permission for that ?

Comment: Check out this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806286/getting-installed-app-size

Comment: have you got any solution, pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

Obviously Google doesn't want us to read other apps' size and is making sure we won't get any information. Most certainly for security reasons, like CPU % and so much other information that are no longer available on Android O! They say reading CPU % could give information about apps' activities on the device LOL.

And referring to this, it'll only get worse:

https://www.xda-developers.com/google-undocumented-hidden-apis-android-p/